# Enabling browser logs doesn't work when working with RemoteWebDriver and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, logging, browser

I have problem with capturing browser logs in my automation tests. I'm launching tests on Firefox in docker container. I tried to use these 2 solutions:

```
    LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
    logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
```

and:

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("devtools.console.stdout.content", true);
    capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
```

After setting these parameters i'm creating RemoteWebDriver instance:

```
    return new RemoteWebDriver(gridHubUrl, capabilities);
```

Finally, when I try to get the logs by:

```
    LogEntries entries = WebDriverProvider.getWebDriver().manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
    Log.logError("BROWSER LOGS");
    for (LogEntry entry : entries) {
        Log.logError(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
    }
```

I'm receiving following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'SFL000923', ip: '10.105.254.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofilevNld2h, rotatable=false, moz:geckodriverVersion=0.27.0, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=dismiss and notify, strictFileInteractability=false, moz:headless=false, platform=ANY, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin=false, webdriver.remote.sessionid=a9c37293-55ee-4342-8aaa-dcc82c357a61, acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserVersion=80.0, moz:shutdownTimeout=60000.0, platformVersion=4.19.76-linuxkit, moz:processID=3254.0, browserName=firefox, moz:buildID=20200818235255, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=linux, setWindowRect=true, moz:webdriverClick=true}]
Session ID: a9c37293-55ee-4342-8aaa-dcc82c357a61
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod.execute(RemoteExecuteMethod.java:35)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteLogs.getRemoteEntries(RemoteLogs.java:81)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteLogs.get(RemoteLogs.java:77)
    at pl.soflab.tacore.utils.BackgroundSteps.afterStep(BackgroundSteps.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:26)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:20)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.HookDefinitionMatch.runStep(HookDefinitionMatch.java:14)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:55)
    at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:42)
    at cucumber.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:56)
    at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:47)
    at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:98)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:55)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:107)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 7 path $
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 7 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1568)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1409)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:542)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:425)
    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:60)
    ... 48 more
```

Additional info: when i'm debugging and checking which log types are available to obtain only client and server logs are returned. Code below:

```
    Set<String> entries1= WebDriverProvider.getWebDriver().manage().logs().getAvailableLogTypes();
    for (String entry1 : entries1) {
        Log.logError(entry1);
    }
```

Server logs indicating that capabilities are correctly set:

```
  12:36:31.281 [main] ERROR Console - Thu Jan 14 12:36:15 CET 2021 INFO Capabilities are: {
  "acceptInsecureCerts": true,
  "browserName": "firefox",
  "firefox_profile": "UEsDBBQACAgIAIdkLlIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHAAAAdXNlci5qc52WyW7bMBBA7\u002f2KwqcWqIks7aU9pWkKFAiaokbQI0GRI4kxRbJcrPjvO9QSO7ZMJT3ZkmbIWd4s0YOj1kH5blE40+IT8ayE7r\u002fUFWmYapkDApoVCsTiw9uSKQ\u002fvv7yJO03BAspY40JSqYGpUPfPBIU2ks\u002foawitcWtSh2CJraWvt8v02TLvlwp0FWpUvPj06bnaaLADJvBHQAAeQHyXzocrtIUrQLXg4qG5pkG\u002fHimvnWmAeu6kDdRFTYNsksrl2YECbIIxyhNutDcKiA\u002fCxJAeA+gwecloXGCFJxhCfaevlfEwHYFRWphWK8ME2qdZlZJRm\u002fZPDXqFEU7RnVa36IgNPl1GGyOYmsnX6A84Z9zo1E7l2BsvK200RrqBpgC36h593hcP3kuUCgb5ceAjxrpEQyl3zNd5XSX1mhgLmsJjAKeZSgC8mroyofA76unLWiiEkxt8ZpwDIhA1eu4RIcrBBZ\u002fNq5DeKrYFcXN+tvppkLaU2o\u002fTwvhK3Ok\u002fUmN+\u002ffkZkXiRuf99ixoLViBKnwvF9HpxzGnvEGVK0QePwUh2yj70x7Y9WonhRlnS1jKAkj7gAX+jdKdISBisZSBDBY7UoXOJhWwAFMPEYNHkUfOJ22hJjZVm8WzaguKp6qJLKV0cuJyyrTtqSLSYYCAaQ1tu71Hk1b0n2lRKN1nzgEcnwxZJUYD\u002fsLKd5IEaJyupqTVK8m0eVQ0tlh0Z\u002fMlk85mh\u002fckkvVzFopFdqfzqXl51ML6s104ek\u002fX4qTqHxKSkoOTZXB2im23H73EhmrJEOVgyaz1B+kxLiy0VULKoppvjU9i5twM\u002f09Ye85ClbcQZ2cdOFdyW9J2xk7+Yk80ePUbk5v72ilwStkvSsXsPbMP6qZJtqoepGGskz9E4LDnDTrCBZUKBqeWLBu2xzw4euqGZNbBHPJmWP34vWywG863vIiuOAKWGdX4Csr0ReYeozZ5dKMPXXXN7UcY8MMfrgZ+58duQnnIiYmOz2UPaX8TkM3AMThsnxXRnPWpGh13ocpqEvmsvxzJEnEKcmc2D7IkWM+xH84vR3gT13XzfTVBsRbHr2dnIJUymjdirIdOPvG4X+qGv+3Xl5GY3zC7adS2BYdQVTXNgBpIacGzyGvj6W9+4vvZfXj\u002fWCBNCJovZzESYXLj\u002fd9FWpqrSy2Gby86AvVrqPL7GHsmCLKRK9GlZ1UGdmHp7quON\u002f9Pi6FgIpMH9sANxkXZKBwcx2q00aQVFsHGRnNlpdnWvSh9tvwrsto1\u002fUEsHCOiJX1qzAwAA8gwAAFBLAQIUABQACAgIAIdkLlLoiV9aswMAAPIMAAAHAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB1c2VyLmpzUEsFBgAAAAABAAEANQAAAOgDAAAAAA==",
  "loggingPrefs": {
    "browser": "ALL",
    "client": "ALL",
    "performance": "ALL",
    "server": "ALL"
  },
  "version": "",
  "webdriver.firefox.marionette": true
}
```

I will be very thankful for responses!

Comment: Any update on this? @Adam

Comment: Firefox doesn't support that (at least wasn't year ago). We switched tests to Chrome and I can obtain the logs now.